# Unwanted image shape cv2

Tags: python, opencv

iam trying to generate images and train a neural network,
i make these images via making an empty np array
`image = np.empty((400, 400), np.int32)` to make the shape on it

`image = cv2.circle(image, (CordX, CordY), rad, color, thickness)`

I don't know how to make it 3 dimensional (image.shape op currently is `400, 400`) and the output should be `400, 400, 3`

Comment: `np.empty((400, 400, 3), np.int32)`!?

Comment: ill try that but keras takes in the third thing bc colors so idk it might do wierd stuff but thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert gray image to RGB, you can simply repeat one channel 3 times:

```py
# Create additional axis
image = image[:, :, None]
print(image.shape) # (400, 400, 1)

# Repeat 3 times along axis 2
image = image.repeat(3, 2)
print(image.shape) # (400, 400, 3)
```

Full example:

```py
image = np.empty((400, 400), np.int32)
image = cv2.circle(image, (200, 200), 20, 100, 3)
image = image[:, :, None].repeat(3, 2)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(image)
plt.show()
```

[image: Resulting image]

Alternatively, you could create RGB image in the first place:

```py
image = np.empty((400, 400, 3), np.int32)
image = cv2.circle(image, (200, 200), 20, (100, 100, 100), 3)
```

This is the same image as above.